# Using multiple dictionaries to populate a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe and wish to input values using pairs of dictionaries.

```
# create count dataframe
range_of_years = range(2012, 2017)
topics = ['ecology','evolution','mathematics','biogeography','neutral theory']
topic_count_timeline = pandas.DataFrame(index = topics, columns = range_of_years)


# dictionary pair
count_dict = {2012: 10, 2013: 20, 2014: 12, 2015: 8, 2016: 9}
paper_topics_dict = {'ecology': 0.7, 'neutral theory': 0.3}
```

I would like to iterate through the dictionary keys, selecting the dataframe cell with column and index that correspond to the keys, and then add the product of the dictionary values to that cell. Such that I would have the resultant dataframe:

```
               2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
ecology           7   14  8.4  5.6  7.7
evolution       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
mathematics     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
biogeography    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
neutral theory    3    6  3.6  2.4  3.3
```

I intend to update the `topic_count_timeline` dataframe using many pairs of dictionaries like `count_dict` and `paper_topic_dict` such that new inputs are summed with the previous incumbent of the cell instead of overwriting.

For example, if a further pair were used update the dataframe...

```
# Additional dictionaries
count_dict2 = {2012: 3, 2013: 2, 2014: 15, 2015: 16, 2016: 13}
paper_topics_dict2 = {'mathematics': 0.6, 'neutral theory': 0.4}
```

The dataframe would then look like this:

```
               2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
ecology           7   14  8.4  5.6  7.7
evolution       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
mathematics     1.8  1.2    9  9.6  5.4
biogeography    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
neutral theory  4.2  6.8  9.6  8.8  8.5
```

Thank you.

Comment: Dictianaries pairs are in list? e.g. in `L = [(count_dict, paper_topics_dict), (count_dict2, paper_topics_dict2)]` ?

Comment: Please remove from `I intend to update the topic_count_timeline dataframe using many pairs` to end, because accepting answer this does not do. Then is all perfectly OK, also I can remove my update of my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need:

```
for k, v in paper_topics_dict.items():
    topic_count_timeline.loc[k] = v

for k, v in count_dict.items():
    topic_count_timeline[k] *= v

print (topic_count_timeline)
               2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
ecology           7   14  8.4  5.6  6.3
evolution       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
mathematics     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
biogeography    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
neutral theory    3    6  3.6  2.4  2.7
```

But if working with dictionary pairs better is for each pair update `defaultdict`, then convert it to `Series`, for `DataFrame` add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for missing columns and index values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count_dict = {2012: 10, 2013: 20, 2014: 12, 2015: 8, 2016: 9}
paper_topics_dict = {'ecology': 0.7, 'neutral theory': 0.3}

count_dict2 = {2012: 3, 2013: 2, 2014: 15, 2015: 16, 2016: 13}
paper_topics_dict2 = {'mathematics': 0.6, 'neutral theory': 0.4}

L = [(count_dict, paper_topics_dict), (count_dict2, paper_topics_dict2)]

d = defaultdict(float)
for a, b in L:
    for k, v in b.items():
        for k2, v2 in a.items():
            d[(k, k2)] += v*v2

df = pd.Series(d).unstack().reindex(index=topics, columns=range_of_years)
print (df)
                2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
ecology          7.0  14.0   8.4   5.6   6.3
evolution        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
mathematics      1.8   1.2   9.0   9.6   7.8
biogeography     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
neutral theory   4.2   6.8   9.6   8.8   7.9
```

Comment: Can I add more that one list `L` of dictionary-pair tuples to the dataframe? The rate at I create dictionaries is limited by the API I am using to extract the data and I would prefer to be able to continually add to the dataframe. Thank you

Comment: @Lorcán - Sure, there is no problem add them.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `combine_first` and create a new df for your `dict`

```
topic_count_timeline.combine_first(pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(list(count_dict.values()))*np.array(list(paper_topics_dict.values()))[:,None],columns=count_dict.keys(),index=paper_topics_dict.keys()))
Out[683]: 
                2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
biogeography     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
ecology          7.0  14.0   8.4   5.6   6.3
evolution        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
mathematics      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
neutral theory   3.0   6.0   3.6   2.4   2.7
```

More info

```
pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(list(count_dict.values()))*np.array(list(paper_topics_dict.values()))[:,None],columns=count_dict.keys(),index=paper_topics_dict.keys())
Out[684]: 
                2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
ecology          7.0  14.0   8.4   5.6   6.3
neutral theory   3.0   6.0   3.6   2.4   2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a function for this and `pd.DataFrame.pipe`.

You can then use the `pipe` syntax for subsequent dictionaries.

```
def update_data(df, counts, topics):
    for k, v in topics.items():
        for k2, v2 in counts.items():
            df.loc[k, k2] = v*v2
    return df

count_dict = {2012: 10, 2013: 20, 2014: 12, 2015: 8, 2016: 9}
paper_topics_dict = {'ecology': 0.7, 'neutral theory': 0.3}

df = df.pipe(update_data, count_dict, paper_topics_dict)

print(df)

#                2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
# ecology           7   14  8.4  5.6  6.3
# evolution       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# mathematics     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# biogeography    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# neutral theory    3    6  3.6  2.4  2.7
```